Scrapy perform action on all retrieved items
I'm a noob on scrapy. I found lots of info about pipelines, but it seems to only treat items individually.
I wish to perform some actions - let's say ordering items - on a complete set, after it's been scraped.
Is there a scrapy wau to do that ?
Thanks

Do you mean that you would like to temporarily store the items you scraped and treat them as a whole sorted list or set?

A Scrapy way to do that would be post-processing the exported data using a separate script.

@vassiliev Either to store all items temporarily, or to be able to post-process retrieved items

@wRAR So no scrapy methods included to say "when you're finished retrieving items, get the batch through this process" ?

@MarvinLeRouge no, that would require storing all the items in the memory (as many people want and many people suggest but which obviously doesn't scale) or reading them back from the whatever storage you put them into (which isn't better than simply writing and running a separate piece of code).

First, I agreed with wRAR. It is inefficient and unreasonable to treat all the items you scraped at one time in Scrapy.
Second, of course you can if you insist on doing it that way, although it is not recommended.
For example, you can define a list property when you initialize your pipeline class, append every item you scraped into that list in the process_item function, and output the ordered items in the list in close_spider function of your pipeline. You can flush it whenever you want in process_item too.
Attention. A big scale of items could cause unexpected result.
The spider class is like:
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    ...
    custom_settings = {
        ...
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            YourPipeline: 301
        }
        ...
    }

The pipeline code is like:
class YourPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_buff = []
        self.buff_size = 50  # you can even define a length limit of the buffer here to flush it when the items are more than this size.

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        pass

   
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.data_buff.append(item)

        if len(self.data_buff) > self.buff_size:
            # If you want, you can sort self.data_buf and then output the items here


    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # sort self.data_buf and then output the items finally

